# Radius of multiple latitude/longitude points

Tags: mysql, ruby, math, geography

I have a program that takes as input an array of lat/long points.  I need to perform a check on that array to ensure that all of the points are within a certain radius.  So, for example, the maximum radius I will allow is 100 miles.  Given an array of lat/long (coming from a MySQL database, could be 10 points could be 10000) I need to figure out if they will all fit in a circle with radius of 100 miles.

Kinda stumped on how to approach this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Finding the center of any given point set is something I haven't tried to figure out, but once you do, the Haversine formula will help you determine if they fall within the radius.

Comment: Wouldn't the center just have the latitude and longitude of the average of the individual latitudes and longitudes, or is there some subtlety of spherical geometry that I'm missing?

Comment: The center is called the barycenter.  This doesn't help, though, because that is not the same as the center of the smallest circle which contains all points (imagine a ton of points on the right, and one on the left - the barycenter will be on the right, but the center of the circle will be in the middle)

Comment: As described, you want to do something that's probably as hard as finding the smallest circle containing your points. That's a tricky (though not impossibly hard) problem. In this situation I'd re-examine the original requirements to see whether or not there is an alternative thing thing you could compute that is good enough for the real underlying problem. You might not want to waste development and CPU time on solving an exact mathematical problem that itself was only an approximation to something that was only vaguely specified to begin with.

Comment: @las3jrock: The center of two points at the same latitude of 45 deg, would be just above 45 deg latitude. Think about how the path of an airplane is "curved" when projected on a Mercator map, even though it's actually traveling straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find [the smallest circle containing all points](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/CG-Applets/Center/centercli.htm), and compare its radius to 100.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest way for me to solve this is by converting the coordinates to (X,Y,Z), then finding the distance along a sphere.

Assuming Earth is a sphere (totally untrue) with radius R...

X = R * cos(long) * cos(lat)

Y = R * sin(long) * cos(lat)

Z = R * sin(lat)

At this point, you can **approximate** the distance between the points using the extension of the pythagorean theorem for threespace:

dist = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)

But to find the actual distance along the surface, you're going to need to know the angle subtended by the two points from the origin (center of the Earth).

Representing your locations as vectors V1 = (X1, Y1, Z1) and V2 = (X2, Y2, Z2), the angle is:

angle = arcsin((V1 x V2) / (|V1||V2|)), where x is the cross-product.

The distance is then:

dist = (Earth's circumference) * angle / (2 * pi)

Of course, this doesn't take into account changes in elevation or the fact that the Earth is wider at the equator.

Apologies for not writing my math in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below involves pretending that the earth is a perfect sphere, which should give a more accurate answer than treating the earth as a flat plane.

To figure out the radius of a set of lat/lon points, you must first ensure that your set of points is "hemispherical", ie. all the points can fit into some arbitrary half of your perfect sphere.

Check out Section 3 in the paper "Optimal algorithms for some proximity problems on the Gaussian sphere with applications" by Gupta and Saluja. I don't have a specific link, but I believe that you can find a copy online for free. This paper is not sufficient to implement a solution. You'll also need Appendix 1 in "Approximating Centroids for the Maximum Intersection of Spherical Polygons" by Ha and Yoo.

I wouldn't use Megiddo's algorithm for doing the linear programming part of the hemisphericity testing. Instead, use Seidel's algorithm for solving Linear Programming problems, described in "Small-Dimensional Linear Programming and Convex Hulls Made Easy" by Raimund Seidel. Also see "Seidel’s Randomized Linear Programming Algorithm" by Kurt Mehlhorn and Section 9.4 from "Real-Time Collision Detection" by Christer Ericson.

Once you have determined that your points are hemispherical, move on to Section 4 of the paper by Gupta and Saluja. This part shows how to actually get the "smallest enclosing circle" for the points.

To do the required quadratic programming, see the paper "A Randomized Algorithm for Solving Quadratic Programs" by N.D. Botkin. [This tutorial](http://www.akiti.ca/QuadProgEx0Constr.html) is helpful, but the paper uses (1/2)x^T G x - g^T x and the web tutorial uses (1/2)x^T H x + c^T x. One adds the terms and the other subtracts, leading to sign-related problems. [Also see this example 2D QP problem](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/QP_solver/Chapter_main.html#Section_65.3). A hint: if you're using C++, the Eigen library is very good.

This method is a little more complicated than some of the 2D methods above, but it should give you more accurate results than just ignoring the curvature of the earth completely. This method also has O(n) time complexity, which is likely asymptotically optimal.

**Note:** The method described above may not handle duplicate data well, so you may want to check for duplicate lat/lon points before finding the smallest enclosing circle.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula).  It gives a way to measure the distance between any two (lat,long) points.  Then use a [smallest enclosing circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem).

I suspect that finding a smallest enclosing circle may be difficult enough on a plane, so to eliminate the subtleties of working with latitude and longitude and spherical geometry, you should probably  consider mapping your points to the XY plane.  That will introduce some amount of distortion, but if your intended scale is 100 miles you can probably live with that.  Once you have a circle and its center on the XY plane, you can always map back to the terrestial sphere and re-check your distances.