# Get record within 10km by lat lng in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gps, sqldatatypes

Sorry for  not handled the GPS data before. may be a newbie question

So , I have created the table that store the gps data like this:

```
table name : request
    id
    lat decimal(10,8)   
    lng decimal(11,8)
```

Recently, I would like to get the data that is 10km within the given GPS point.

```
e.g. Given GPS lat: 22, lng: 114 , found all data within 10km
```

And I found there is a data type called "point". And a SQL query related

```
SELECT *
FROM request
WHERE MBRContains
(
LineString
(
Point (
@lng + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
 @lat + 10 / 111.1
),
 Point (
@lng - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
 @lat - 10 / 111.1
)
),
 POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(22 114)')
)
```

It return 0 result even there should be some result eg. I have some record that lat is 22.1 , 114.1 . How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: i am also interested to know this solution

Comment: thanks for upvote , looking forward to any idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radius of 40 kilometers using latitude and longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850336/radius-of-40-kilometers-using-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reference this question, it was closed as a duplicate but the list of duplicates give you a pretty good overview of the problemset and solutions.

[Radius of 40 kilometers using latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850336/radius-of-40-kilometers-using-latitude-and-longitude)