# OpenStreetMap Proximity search using mySQL

Tags: mysql, geo, openstreetmap

I'm just playing around with a dataset of my region generated by JOSM. I moved it into a mySQL DB with the 0.6 API scheme using Osmosis and now I'm desperately trying the following:

I want to get all streets of a city. 
AFAIK there is no tag/relation in the OSM data to determine this so I tried it using a proximity search to get all nodes in a radius around a node representing the city center.

Most of the time I looked at the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574691/144701)

What I got is the following SQL code that should get me the closest 100 nodes around the node with id 36187002 and within a radius of 10km.

```
set @nodeid = 36187002;
set @dist = 10;
select longitude, latitude into @mylon, @mylat from nodes where id=@nodeid limit 1;


SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(@mylon) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians(  longitude ) - radians(@mylat) ) + sin( radians(@mylon) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance
FROM nodes HAVING distance < @dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 100;
```

Well.. it doesn't work. :( I guess the main problem is that OSM lats/lons are multiplied by 10.000.000 and I don't know how I can correct this function to make it work.

Any ideas about this? All solutions/alternatives are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster to add extra columns to your table for the latitude and longitude expressed as the `double` data type (so the trigonometric functions stand a chance) - you may want to go further and precalculate the xaxis, yaxis and zaxis as columns (again, stored as `double`)

So, your new columns are loosely (you may need to add data type conversions as required):

```
XAxis   = cos(radians(Latitude / 10000000)) * cos(radians(Longitude / 10000000))
YAxis   = cos(radians(Latitude / 10000000)) * sin(radians(Longitude / 10000000))
ZAxis   = sin(radians(Latitude / 10000000))
```

Then, your proximity search becomes:

```
set @nodeid = 36187002;
set @dist = 10;
SELECT XAxis, YAxis, ZAxis
INTO @CntXAxis, @CntYAxis, @CntZAxis
FROM nodes
WHERE id=@nodeid limit 1;

SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos(
             CASE
                WHEN nodes.XAxis * @CntXAxis
              + nodes.YAxis * @CntYAxis
              + nodes.ZAxis * @CntZAxis > 1.0 THEN 1.0
              ELSE  nodes.XAxis * @CntXAxis
              + nodes.YAxis * @CntYAxis
              + nodes.ZAxis * @CntZAxis 
             END
           ) AS Distance
FROM nodes 
HAVING Distance < @dist 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the query a little and it works. 
Here my code:

```
    set @nodeid = 122317;
    set @dist = 10;
    select lon, lat into @mylon, @mylat from nodes where id=@nodeid limit 1;

    SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos(
    sin(radians(@mylat)) * sin(radians(lat)) +
    cos(radians(@mylat)) * cos( radians(lat)) * 
    cos(radians(lon) - radians(@mylon)) 
    )) 
    AS distance
    FROM nodes having distance <@dist
```

i´ve got the formula from the german wikipedia and it works fine. I've had in in some ruby code fist, but its also work as an sql-query.

To select some special nodes i added this

```
(select nodes.id,lat,lon,k,v from nodes join node_tags on nodes.id=node_tags.id where k='public_transport') as stations
```

as the FROM condition to specify the tags of the nodes. (Of course it changes the lat/log access to stations.lat/stations.log in the code above.