# What is the best way to calculate distance on earth with 2 coordinates in meters in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation, coordinates

I have got 2 sets google maps geo coordinates. Like 51.2, 6.1 and 50.3 and 5.5.

How do i calculate the distance between those 2 coordinates in meters with mysql?

I'm looking for the geo calculation, with earth radius and stuff. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are these coordinates lat/lon pairs, or coordinates on a map?  How  are they obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)