# Haversine's formula in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, haversine

I'm having the following lines in my code

```
    query = "SELECT id, " \
        "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( %(lat)i ) ) * " \
        "cos( radians( %(lng)i ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * " \
        "sin( radians( %(lat)i ) ) ) ) AS `distance` from message where" \
        " `distance` <= %(drange)d" % {'lat': float(lat), 'lng': float(lng), 'drange': int(drange)}
    print query
    messages = db.session.query(Message).from_statement(query).all()
```

I get the following error when I use this

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'") 'SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( 0 ) ) * cos( radians( 0 ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( 0 ) ) ) ) AS `distance` from message where `distance` <= 50' ()
```

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry if i am missing somethig but how calculated value is connected to message db table (i mean all values for calculation you are passing outside as well as expected value for calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference the named expression (`distance`) in the `WHERE` clause (I don't know if this is generally true for all database systems, but it is at least so for MySQL). You can use `HAVING` instead (see option C).

Options:

A. Repeat the expression again in the where clause:

```
SELECT id, (long_formula) as distance FROM message WHERE (long_formula) <= ...
```

B. Use a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id, (long_formula) AS distance FROM message) inner_query 
WHERE distance <= ...
```

C. Use the `HAVING` clause (I have used SQL for years but was not aware of `HAVING` until I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula/574736#574736)):

```
SELECT id, (long_formula) as distance FROM message HAVING distance <= ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question but you can increase readability of your query if start using """
For example your query could be modified the following way:

```
query = """
            SELECT id,
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( %(lat)i ) ) *  cos( radians( %(lng)i ) - radians(-122) ) +
              sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( %(lat)i ) ) ) ) AS distance
            FROM message
            WHERE distance <= %(drange)d
         """ % {'lat': float(lat), 'lng': float(lng), 'drange': int(drange)}
```

Also just for me is this correctly to use " AS 'distance'" instead of " AS distance" as alias i mean is it allowed to use " ' "?