# How can I view the error preventing me from creating a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, warnings

I'm trying to implement a Haversine distance function as desribed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389859/why-does-this-mysql-stored-function-give-different-results-than-to-doing-the-calc).

Whenever I run it though, either on the command line or through PhpMyAdmin, I get the following error:

```
#1607 - Cannot create stored routine `haversine`. Check warnings
```

The problem is that when I run `SHOW WARNINGS;` I get a 0 row result set.

Is this a common problem? How do I view the warnings? (If it's relevant, I'm running MySQL 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is any better way. What I have been doing is to create it very simple and incomplete and test at each added bit of functionality. Why don't you post yours?

Look at this question:

[How do you debug MySQL stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273437/how-do-you-debug-mysql-stored-procedures)

Comment: I didn't see the need to post my stored procedure as it's a verbatim copy of the one on the question I linked to. This is also a reason why I'm reluctant to start taking it to bits; I know it works elsewhere, so it's probably my installation of MySQL that's the problem.