# how a script can load ads posted by users order by distance?

Tags: php, google-maps

One of my friend wants to have a website which calculates the distance between ads poster location and a visitor. For example when I would visit this website it would display ads which are near to my location It would also display "30 km away from you".

Where I should start from? Is there any idea? Or any script which I can use for this method?

I have seen google map api but I dont get idea how to display my database records as per distance.

Please guide me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the haversine formula in MySQL and download an open source zipcode database.  Import it, and work the query to your desired result.  Hope that helps.

[Haversine Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385452/a-custom-mysql-function-to-calculate-the-haversine-distance)

[Zip Code Database Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/)