# Python, SQLAlchemy: Create bounding circle for GPS Coordinates?

Tags: python, sql, gps, sqlalchemy, gis

I'd like to be able to put in a GPS coordinate (latitude and longitude) into a python function and have it return the range of latitudes and longitudes which will fall within a certain distance from the original point.

What I ultimately want to do is to take a GPS coordinate and be able to go into my database of GPS coordinates using SQLAlchemy and return the coordinates which fall within a certain range, for example within 1 mile.

Is there any framework that does that or do you have any advice for going about solving this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer from the link in the comment that Carl left was actually the solution I went with:

[MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula/574736#574736)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/) which adds geographic support to PostgreSQL. The [`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) function lets you find points which are within a certain distance of another point:

```
SELECT name
FROM some_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geography_1,
    geography_2,
    distance_in_meters
);
```

[GeoAlchemy](http://www.geoalchemy.org/intro.html) adds extensions to SQLAlchemy for working with spatial databases. You might want to try using that in conjunction with PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the 'bounding box' method. It basically draws a (~square) box around a given point and finds all the points in that box.

For max_distance in miles and z as a point with latitude and longitude you can use:

```
dist_range = max_distance / 69.172

lat_range = (z.latitude-dist_range, z.latitude+dist_range)
lon_range = (z.longitude-dist_range, z.longitude+dist_range)
```

Then your query can include the entries for which co-ordinates fall in this range.

This is not very accurate, and its accuracy drops as max_distance increases. However, for simple geo-queries, it works great and doesn't use any location-specific extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think [geoalchemy](https://geoalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/0.5/tutorial.html/) will resolve your problems