# Using the Haversine formula with PostgreSQL and PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, haversine

On my site I'm trying to get locations nearby.

I'm trying to use the Haversine formula for this.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
- [MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)
- [Calculate zipcodes in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885034/calculate-zipcodes-in-range)

I'm using the following query to get all the locations within a 25km radius.

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(4.6265) ) + sin( radians(51.8391) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM shops
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY name asc
```

However I think some functions may be MySQL only, because I get the following error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function radians(text) does not exist LINE 1: ...id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( l... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. in ...

Or perhaps it has to do with tha fact I have to change the text `lat` in my query. But I don't know what it should be.

51.8391 and 4.6265 are the long and lat of my 'starting' point.

Any help is much appreciated since I don't have any idea what to change :-)

**EDIT**

It looks like that the problem is where I try to do: `radians(lat)`.

lat is a column in my table.

When I try to use `rad()` as hakre suggested the error changes to: `function rad(numeric) does not exist`

**EDIT 2**

Now we're getting somewhere.

The datatype of the columns where indeed set as text (as suggested by mu is too short).

I've changed it to double precision.

However now I get another error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "distance" does not exist LINE 1: ...adians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM shops HAVING distance <... ^ in ...

But I thought I made an alias in the select. Any ideas?

Also if you guys think this should go in another question just let me know and I will close this one.

Comment: @hakre: nopez no luck. See edit

Comment: Was a quick shot only (sorry it did not work :)), see how to define functions in postgresql, so you can apply that in queries more easily (and faster) (and see as well http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgsphere/).

Comment: NB: this isn't the Haversine formula - this is the simpler cosine-based formula. Haversine is much more complicated, but is more accurate unless using high precision (e.g. double) arithmetic.

Comment: personally I think the new bit should be a separate question, but there's plenty questions here already about "having vs where"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL does have a [`radians`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) function:

> `radians(dp)`
>   degrees to radians

but `radians` wants a floating point argument and you are trying to give it a string of some sort:

> Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function radians(**text**)
>   [...] HINT: No function matches the given name and **argument types**. You might need to add **explicit type casts**.

Emphasis mine. Apparently your `lat` and `lng` columns are `char(n)`, `varchar(n)`, or `text` columns. You should fix the column types for `lat` and `lng` to be `numeric`, `float`, or some other [floating point type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT); in the mean time, you can [cast your strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) by hand and hope that you don't have any broken data:

```
radians(cast(lat as double precision))
```

MySQL does a lot of implicit type conversions, PostgreSQL is rather more strict and requires you to say exactly what you mean.

---

**Update for the second problem**: The `HAVING` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause so column aliases in the `SELECT` are not generally available anywhere else in the query. You have a couple options, you can repeat your big ugly Haversine:

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(4.6265) ) + sin( radians(51.8391) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM shops
HAVING ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(4.6265) ) + sin( radians(51.8391) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 25
ORDER BY name asc
```

Or use a derived table to avoid repeating yourself:

```
select id, distance
from (
    select id, name, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.8391) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(4.6265) ) + sin( radians(51.8391) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) as distance
    from shops
) as dt
where distance < 25.0
order by name asc
```

Comment: Great. Looks like that was indeed the problem. I now get another error however :( Thanks for your help so far! So edited question if you like, or if you don't wanna also fine! :)

Comment: many many thanks! I will use the first option since the formula is already in a variable.

Comment: Worked: 2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt((sin(radians((lat2 - lat1) / 2))) ^ 2 + cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * (sin(radians((lon2 - lon1) / 2))) ^ 2))

Answer (score 2):

Conversion to radians is trivial:

```
radians(n) = n * PI / 180.0
```

Comment: Would that be possible to do with column(-data)? Since that is what needs to be done I think. Not sure though... Also see my edit

Comment: PostgreSQL has a `radians` function, the problem is that `lat` and `lng` are not numeric.

Comment: sure - just store radian data in your DB instead of degrees.  better yet, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409035/quicker-way-to-calculate-geographic-distance-between-two-points/6409253#6409253

Comment: and like @mu says - store numbers _as numbers_, not _as text_!!

Comment: @Alnitak: yeah yeah that was just me being dumb :)