# Searching mySQL database for near by coordinates

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, database, xcode4

I doing an iPhone application which has an external database in this case i am using mySql.

i wan to store coordinates into the database and later i want to search the database using a coordinates to return only the coordinates that are near to the coordinates i am querying.

Example

```
-----------------
    Database    |
-----------------
1- Coordinate A |
2- Coordinate B |
3- Coordinate C |
-----------------
```

search using Coordinate D lets say coordinate A and Coordinate C are near to Coordinate D lets say with 5KM radius distance then my query result to show 
Coordinates A, Coordinates C
and ignore Coordinate B as it is not near to Coordinate D

Does anyone have any idea on What format should my database be in ? 
How to query the database for near by coordinates ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Comment: exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula

Answer (score 0):

Store your coordinates as 2 columns, each a float. So you'd have your table structure like:

```
lon float(X,Y)
lat float(X,Y)
```

Where `X` and `Y` are your desired precision.

For searching you can use the [Haversine distance formula](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=haversine&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=haversine%20formula#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=haversine%20formula%20mysql&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=cd4659920e981d1f&biw=1084&bih=584&pf=p&pdl=500) for geo / spatial searching with a fixed distance (your 5KM)