# mysql distance between search

Tags: mysql, select, distance

so I have two tabels where one has a list of all postcodes with long and lat and the other has store data with long and lat.

What I need to know is how do I find all the stores that match the long and lat from a postcode within 30km

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) ([MySQL implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/31671)) to calculate the distance between them. Return rows which have a distance of less or equal to `30`.

Answer (score 0):

Review this http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlon_formula.html for formula, and put the formula on select statement and order by the distance