# sql query with multiple where statements

Tags: mysql

I am having a rather, for me, complicated mysql query on which I am totally stuck and cannot find any answer for online.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
items.*
FROM
items
INNER JOIN
items_meta_data
WHERE
(
        (meta_key = 'lat' AND meta_value >= '55')
    OR
        (meta_key = 'lat' AND meta_value <= '65')
)
AND
(
        (meta_key = 'long' AND meta_value >= '20')
    OR
        (meta_key = 'long' AND meta_value <= '30')
)
GROUP BY
item_id
```

Of course I have tested the query with only 1 statement and that works fine. So, if I only pass the long or lat part, then I get results. Only when I try to stitch them together, I get different results.

Thanks for the help in advance!

The table structure is as follows:

```
Table items:
ID
item_name
item_description

Table meta:
meta_id
item_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

**Solution**

To whoever is interested I finally managed to tackle this problem. Thank you all for your help and insides.

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS items.* 
FROM
    items
INNER JOIN
    items_meta ON (items.ID = items_meta.post_id)
INNER JOIN
    items_meta AS m1 ON (items.ID = m1.post_id)
WHERE
    1=1
    AND
    items.post_type = 'post'
    AND
    (items.post_status = 'publish')
    AND
    ( (items_meta.meta_key = 'lat' AND CAST(items_meta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '55'   AND '65')
    AND
    (m1.meta_key = 'long' AND CAST(m1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '20' AND '30') )
GROUP BY
    items.ID
ORDER BY
    items.date
DESC
```

Comment: Can you clarify specifically what happens when you "stitch them together"?  What does the data you're querying look like and what results do you get?

Comment: We can assume this is not a bug in mysql, so you need to say what you expected, and what you instead observed. What data are you putting through the query?

Comment: You're searching for a database row where `meta_key` is both `'lat'` and `'long'`. I'm not sure that's possible...

Comment: Nothing happens the results are empty. No query error or nothing else. Also no results thou I know for sure that there is an entry with the exact values as specified above... so it should at least return that one row.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to consider that `GROUP BY` happens after the `WHERE` clause conditions have been evaluated. And the `WHERE` clause always considers only one row, meaning that in your query, the `meta_key` conditions will always prevent any records from being selected, since **one column cannot have multiple values for one row**.

The `meta_value` checks given in your question also are redundant - If a value is allowed to be both smaller and greater than a given value, then its actual value doesn't matter at all - the check can be omitted.

But this hints at your problem - you actually want to check *two separate rows* of your `meta` table; according to one of your comments you want to check for places less than a certain distance from a given location. To get correct distances, you'd actually have to use some kind of proper distance function (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula) for details). But this SQL should give you an idea how to start, it shows how to join the `item` element with the two entries in the `meta` table that are needed (one with `meta_key` = 'lat' and one with `meta_key` = 'long'):

```
SELECT items.* FROM items i, meta m1, meta m2
    WHERE i.item_id = m1.item_id and i.item_id = m2.item_id
    AND m1.meta_key = 'lat' AND m1.meta_value >= 55 AND m1.meta_value <= 65
    AND m2.meta_key = 'lng' AND m2.meta_value >= 20 AND m2.meta_value <= 30
```

Comment: That is probably where my mistake lays. I need to find the items within a distance of about 10km of the current location. For testing I added the current coordinates to the query. Those should be 5km smaller then current location and 5km bigger then current location.

Comment: Aaah, that's enlightening. But why then compare two times with the same value? What you will need is a double join, once for the lng and once for the lat value, I will try to work it into my answer

Comment: Yes I am so messed up after fighting with this for hours that I find it difficult to explain. Thank you for your patience! I changed my initial post query to match more what I am after... I will edit it a bit more to get a more complete view.

Answer (score 11):

This..

```
(
        (meta_key = 'lat' AND meta_value >= '60.23457047672217')
    OR
        (meta_key = 'lat' AND meta_value <= '60.23457047672217')
)
```

is the same as

```
(
        (meta_key = 'lat')
)
```

Adding it all together (the same applies to the `long` filter) you have this impossible WHERE clause which will give no rows because `meta_key` cannot be 2 values in one row

```
WHERE
    (meta_key = 'lat' AND meta_key = 'long' )
```

You need to review your operators to make sure you get the correct logic

Comment: This is not true. Each item has multiple meta data rows in the meta table. So I am searching for items which match to multiple matches.

Comment: @user1117774: yes. it is true. Logic dictates your WHERE is wrong

Comment: Every item in table items has multiple metadata rows attached to it from the meta table. So for example item with ID = 1 has in the meta table the following rows attached to it:

rowID = 1, itemID = 1, meta_key = lat, meta_value = '1234'
rowID = 2, itemID = 1, meta_ket = long, meta_valye = '5678'

Answer (score 4):

What is `meta_key`?  Strip out all of the `meta_value` conditionals, reduce, and you end up with this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
meta_data
WHERE
(
        (meta_key = 'lat')
)
AND
(
        (meta_key = 'long')
)
GROUP BY
item_id
```

Since `meta_key` can never simultaneously equal two different values, no results will be returned.

---

Based on comments throughout this question and answers so far, it sounds like you're looking for something more along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
meta_data
WHERE
(
    (meta_key = 'lat')
    AND
    (
        (meta_value >= '60.23457047672217')
        OR
        (meta_value <= '60.23457047672217')
    )
)
OR
(
    (meta_key = 'long')
    AND
    (
        (meta_value >= '24.879140853881836')
        OR
        (meta_value <= '24.879140853881836')
    )
)
GROUP BY
item_id
```

Note the `OR` between the top-level conditionals.  This is because you want records which are `lat` *or* `long`, since no single record will ever be `lat` *and* `long`.

I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish by the inner conditionals.  *Any* non-null value will match those numbers.  So maybe you can elaborate on what you're trying to do there.  I'm also not sure about the purpose of the `GROUP BY` clause, but that might be outside the context of this question entirely.

Comment: @user1117774: But no single row will match this query.  Maybe you want the `AND` in the reduced version to be an `OR`?  Update the question with the table structure and we can help build a query.

Comment: The query should match 2 rows from the meta table per item to be valid indeed.

Comment: @user1117774: Then you definitely want to use `OR` between the `lat` and `long` checks.  Something like: `WHERE (key='lat' AND value=...) OR (key='long' AND value=...)`.  You want to test the `lat` and `long` individually and return any row which matches either one, since no one row will ever match both.

Comment: @user1117774: I've elaborated further in my answer.

Comment: Thanks David. I am following you but... if you are on a certain location on the globe you always have a latitude and longitude location. If I would like to show the items within 10km's of your current location I would need to match that both the latitude and longitude values are between the current ones... right?

Comment: @user1117774: Yes, and the logical `OR` in this case will help with that.  It sounds like you think the `AND` means something different than it actually does.  You're trying to ask the database, "Give me the lat records AND the long records."  That's not how the query engine works.  You need to ask it, "Give me any record which is a lat OR is a long."  Then further refine from there, such as, "Give me any record which is a lat AND within this given range, OR any record which is a long AND within this given range."  The WHERE clause matches row-by-row, it knows nothing of a conceptual globe.

Answer (score 1):

Can we see the structure of your table? If I am understanding this, then the assumption made by the query is that a record can be only `meta_key - 'lat'` or `meta_key = 'long'` not both because each row only has one `meta_key` column and can only contain 1 corresponding value, not 2. That would explain why you don't get results when you connect the with an `AND`; it's impossible.

Comment: I added a short description of the table structure in the first post. I should have done that earlier, thanks for mentioning it