# Objective C - What is wrong with this great circle distance calculation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, gps

I am trying to do the [great circle distance calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula). As you should be able to glean, the `Location` class has the properties listed in the calculation.

```
- (NSNumber *)greatCircleDistanceFrom:(Location *)other
{
    // Unpack all the NSNumbers into doubles so we can manipulate them
    double selfCosRadLat = [self.cosRadLat doubleValue];
    double otherCosRadLat = [other.cosRadLat doubleValue];
    double selfRadLng = [self.radLng doubleValue];
    double otherRadLng = [other.radLng doubleValue];
    double selfSinRadLat = [self.sinRadLat doubleValue];
    double otherSinRadLat = [other.sinRadLat doubleValue];

    // Multiplying by 3959 calculates the distance in miles.
    double d = acos(selfCosRadLat
                    * otherCosRadLat
                    * cos(selfRadLng - otherRadLng)
                    + selfSinRadLat
                    * otherSinRadLat
                    ) * 3959.0;

    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:d];
}
```

Half the time I run my unit test, I get the right value. The other half, I get `6218.78265778`.

Comment: You can use built-in distanceFromLocation method of CLLocation.

Comment: Does that use Great Circle Distance Formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your incoming `Location` value isn't `nil` or 0,0.  It seems like the reason you'd get a constant like that is because it is doing the math as if it were at 0°,0°.  Are you 6218 miles from approximately west Africa?  If so, your function is working great, but the method calling it isn't providing real values some of the time.

Comment: Actually, thank you. I see now that the calculation fails because the values were 0,0. However, they shouldn't be 0,0. I now have a new problem with Core Data...

Comment: At least you no longer have this problem :)

Comment: Yes, [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827495/core-data-cascading-calculation-not-sticking).