# Core Data: Custom Setter Which Does Cascading Calculation Failing

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class called `Location` with the following automatically generated declaration,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Location : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cosRadLat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * radLat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * radLng;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sinRadLat;

@end
```

In an objective-c category, I have created two methods to calculate the other properties based on the latitude and longitude,

```
- (double)degreesToRadians:(NSNumber *)degrees
{
    double radians = ([degrees doubleValue] * M_PI) / 180.0;
    return radians;
}

- (void)setLatitude:(NSNumber *)newLat longitude:(NSNumber *)newLng
{
    [self setLatitude:newLat];
    [self setLongitude:newLng];

    // Make calculations
    double dblRadLat = [self degreesToRadians:newLat];
    double dblRadLng = [self degreesToRadians:newLng];
    double dblCosRadLat = cos(dblRadLat);
    double dblSinRadLat = sin(dblRadLat);

    // and set their values
    [self setRadLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:dblRadLat]];
    [self setRadLng:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:dblRadLng]];
    [self setCosRadLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:dblCosRadLat]];
    [self setSinRadLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:dblSinRadLat]];
}
```

When I run my unit tests, half the time I get this:

```
Lat 40.7302133
Lng -74.0003337
RadLat 0.7108763271245849
RadLng -1.291549470639518
CosRadLat 0.7577903652576623
SinRadLat 0.6524980937310535
```

The other half, I get this:

```
Lat 40.7302133
Lng -74.0003337
RadLat 0
RadLng 0
CosRadLat 0
SinRadLat 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

## UNIT TEST

Here is my function I use to save the context in the unit test,

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSLog(@"%@ saveContext", self.name);

    NSError *saveError = nil; 
    STAssertTrue([self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError], @"Failed to save context to persistent store: %@", saveError);
}
```

And here is how I am calling it,

```
// Constants we will check to ensure our calcluations are correct
// 1st Location
double const LAT = 40.7292540;
double const LNG = -73.9988530;
double const RAD_LAT = 0.710859584;
double const RAD_LNG = -1.29152363;
double const SIN_RAD_LAT = 0.652485406;
double const COS_RAD_LAT = 0.75780129;
double const accuracy = 0.00000001;

/** Run before each test. Populates the database with objects to play with.
 */
- (void)setUp
{
    NSLog(@"%@ setUp", self.name);

    // Creates our persistent store in memory and initializes our managed object context for us.
    [super setUp];

    // Create a new Location
    Location *location = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Using the setLatitude:longitude: method, which cascades the calculation for all other values
    [location setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:LAT] longitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:LNG]];

    // Check if it has properly calculated the values we asked for
    double lat = [[location latitude] doubleValue];
    double lng = [[location longitude] doubleValue];
    double rad_lat = [[location radLat] doubleValue];
    double rad_lng = [[location radLng] doubleValue];
    double sin_rad_lat = [[location sinRadLat] doubleValue];
    double cos_rad_lat = [[location cosRadLat] doubleValue];

    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(LAT, lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", LAT, lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(LNG, lng, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", LNG, lng);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(RAD_LAT, rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", RAD_LAT, rad_lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(RAD_LNG, rad_lng, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", RAD_LNG, rad_lng);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(SIN_RAD_LAT, sin_rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", SIN_RAD_LAT, sin_rad_lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(COS_RAD_LAT, cos_rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", COS_RAD_LAT, cos_rad_lat);

    // Saves the managed object context into the persistent store.
    [self saveContext];
}
```

This part usually works. What happens is, `setup` is called, it runs this test, and here is where it fails,

```
- (Location *)fetchLastLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@ getLastLocation", self.name);

    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [self fetchEntity: @"Location"];

    Location *location = (Location *)[mutableFetchResults lastObject];

    return location;
}

/** Tests to see if the values stick after saving and fetching
 */
- (void)testCalculatedValuesStick
{
    Location *location = [self fetchLastLocation];

    NSLog(@"Stick: %@", location);

    // Check if it has properly calculated the values we asked for
    double lat = [[location latitude] doubleValue];
    double lng = [[location longitude] doubleValue];
    double rad_lat = [[location radLat] doubleValue];
    double rad_lng = [[location radLng] doubleValue];
    double sin_rad_lat = [[location sinRadLat] doubleValue];
    double cos_rad_lat = [[location cosRadLat] doubleValue];

    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(LAT, lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", LAT, lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(LNG, lng, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", LNG, lng);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(RAD_LAT, rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", RAD_LAT, rad_lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(RAD_LNG, rad_lng, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", RAD_LNG, rad_lng);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(SIN_RAD_LAT, sin_rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", SIN_RAD_LAT, sin_rad_lat);
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(COS_RAD_LAT, cos_rad_lat, accuracy, @"Wanted: %f Got: %f", COS_RAD_LAT, cos_rad_lat);
}
```

Do you think my unit test has anything to do with it?

Comment: Your use of `NSNumber*` conversion back and forth is killing me!  Use straight `double` already!

Comment: Well, since this is Core Data I have to store the `latitude`, `longitude`, etc. as `NSNumber*`. But, I actually did try just using `double` where I could and it did not change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your method is making variables named radLat, but that is also a property of your instance - I feel like you may have pointer troubles happening.

Try changing the name of your method variables (`double radLat` etc) to something *different* and see if that changes how your code is running.  I think that code isn't behaving the way you're expecting it to - though knowing more about the code operating on your `Location` class will help.

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect the changes in your comment and this answer. I gave you +1, but I still am having the same problem.

Comment: Are you certain your unit tests are truly reflecting this particular bit of code and not something later on down the line?

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. When `[super setUp]` was being called, I was making another `Location` and saving it as well. There was a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) going on, and which ever was saved last would be returned by `fetchLastLocation` and compared to what I assumed was the right location, but half the time would be wrong depending on who won the race. Thanks Tim, it was my unit test!

Comment: Glad you got it!  Now I need to try to snipe *all* of your questions on SO.