# Google map. Get nearest by coordinates

Tags: php, jquery, database, maps, coordinates

I have an MySQL database with thousands of entries with coordinates.

An entry looks like this: id, dt, img, long, lat

For now, I list the top 20 from mysql. But how do I get the 20 entries most near a given point?
The given point is "center" in the code below.

Images

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var myMarkers = {"markers": [   
    <?php 
      $query="SELECT id, dt, img, long, lat FROM places LIMIT 20";
      $result=mysql_query($query);
      $num=mysql_numrows($result);
      $i=0;
      while ($i < $num) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pl_id = $row[0];
        $pl_dt = $row[1];
        $pl_img = $row[2];
        $pl_longitud = $row[3];
        $pl_latitud = $row[4];
        $pres = "Text is coming.";
    ?>
    {"latitude": "<?php echo $pl_latitud ?>", "longitude":"<?php echo $pl_longitud ?>", "icon":"<?php echo $pl_img ?>", "baloon_text":"<?php echo $pres ?>"},
    <?php
        $i++;
      }
    ?>
    ]};
    $("#map").mapmarker({ zoom        : 10,
                          center      : '<?php echo $pl_latitud; ?>, <?php echo $pl_longitud; ?>',
                          markers : myMarkers
                        });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: (Pretty much exact) Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula

Comment: BTW, is there a way to tell the distance from given center?

Comment: Sam Dufel: Dont understand that code.

Comment: have you tried the google maps link in the question @SamDufel posted? I think you need the Haversine formula sql query from that page: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch

Comment: @andernicken - the first answer to the question I linked has the exact sql query to sort locations by distance using lat/long.  If you want an explanation of the math, just look at the wikipedia article on great circle distance.  I don't see what else you could need.