# Compare closest value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to compare two values against the values in my table to find the closest one, but each time I try the code (see below) I just get the first row returned

```
    SELECT latitude, longitude, ABS(latitude - 53.316494), ABS(longitude - -6.253541) AS distance
    FROM station
    ORDER BY distance
    LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is `LIMIT 1` intentional?

Comment: Yes, as i only want the closest

Comment: How do you define closest?. This you should define as a computed var and order in your select ascending.

Comment: this will return 4 value of the first line as you just ask select and no Where condition. maybe with betwin?

Comment: @ssbb I don't think between will work here for me

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, ABS(latitude - 53.316494), ABS(longitude - -6.253541)
FROM station
LIMIT 1;
```

But "Compare closest value in MySQL" in latitude and longitude means to find closest way 
Should looks like:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, ABS(latitude - 53.316494), ABS(longitude - -6.253541)
FROM station
ORDER BY (POW((latitude - 53.316494,2) + POW((longitude - -6.253541),2)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

[image]