# How to search nearby places stored in my database?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a web app where the user sets a place in a map (Google Maps API) and I store the coordinates in a database.

At another page, I want to do a search which consists in getting my local coordinates and retrieve nearby places previously stored at my database based on a radius.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use this SQL select statement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/4195406 depends on what radius you want, you can change the line `HAVING distance < 25` to your desired number.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use what is called the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM your_table HAVING distance < 5";
```

Where `$lat` and `$lng` are the coordinates of your point, and `lat` / `lng` are your table columns. The above will list the locations within a 5 nm range. Replace `3959` by `6371` to change to kilometers.

Comment: May you please explain your formula since I could not find the formula you used in the [Haversine formula link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) you gave above. Cheers! :)

Comment: This is the formula explained in the wikipedia link. I am no mathematician so it'd be hard to give more insights than what the linked page does. It's just *translated* for MySQL. It basically allows to find points within a certain radius, on the surface of the earth, which, as you might know, is not flat ;)

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a "store locator script", for which google has an intro to here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

what you'll need to do is to create a backend which allows your user to enter each place into the database. It's quite a large task and if I were you, I would take an open source script or similar and adapt it to your needs.

for example:

https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin

I would do a search for "free store locator script" and try their demos, see what appeals to you the most.