# How to find nearest location by latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

This is the `loc_coordinate` table structure:

[image]

Below is the code, to fetch the nearest places from database and display the place name stored in database itself.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$lat = "3.107685";
$lon = "101.7624521";

        $sql="SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS 'distance' FROM loc_coordinate HAVING 'distance'<='10' ORDER BY 'distance' ASC";
        $stmt =$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();


        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
          echo $row['place'];
        }

?>
```

The error shown for this:

> Fatal error: in C:\wamp\www\mysite\by_coor.php on line 8
>
> PDOException: in C:\wamp\www\mysite\by_coor.php on line 8

`echo $sql` shows this:

> SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(3.107685 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) +
>   COS(3.107685 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((101.7624521
>   â€“ lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS 'distance'
>   FROM loc_coordinate HAVING 'distance'<='10' ORDER BY 'distance' ASC

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error. This is the site I referred to for the SQL query: http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/

Comment: `echo $sql` and see what is wrong there.

Comment: @u_mulder, updated the result of echo $sql above in my post

Comment: it seems you forget the $ in SIN(lat * PI() / 180), check your variables

Comment: SO - what is `â€“` in your query?

Comment: is it definitely a standard minus sign?

Comment: @RamRaider yes the minus

Comment: @YosraNagati, thanks I updated lat with $lat..but still he same error..btw any idea why PI value is not shown above? DO I need to include any library for that?

Comment: It is the supposed minus sign - replace with a definite minus sign - just tried this query on my db and it failed because of it - replaced with a minus sign and it was ok - sort of. The query ran but no idea if it is going to return data because I don't have you data or tables.

Comment: @RamRaider, I updated the html in my code with charset=utf-8" and no problem with the minus sign now..Also I updated the table structure in my post above

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Comment: @u_mulder  ... the old minus / hyphen / endash / emdash confusion! Good catch.  A known hazard of cutting and pasting code from blog posts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this

```
     SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $lat - LatOnTable) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $lat * pi()/180) * COS(LatOnTable * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $long - LongOnTable) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance  
from yourTable  
having  distance <= 10 
order by distance
```

substitute LatOnTable with the latitude table column name , and longOnTable with you longitude column name in your table .

Comment: tried, no error shown but no result returned as well. I changed 10 miles into 100 miles still no result

Comment: my suggestion is to try it on your database first, then execute into the php code

Comment: I changed the <=10 into .>=10 and can see the results

Comment: it works in when I tried in database with hardcoded lat and lon values...I shall be able to solve it now.. Thank you

Comment: check this if you want to undersatnd the logic behind it  check this link http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out

Comment: This is amazing, but can anyone walk through the actual formula? No idea why it works :/

Comment: Adding `limit 1` on the end will get the "nearest" location, instead of a list of the nearest locations.

Comment: i am getting SQL Syntax Error. 
`SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( 30.720043 - lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( 30.720043 * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( 76.706276 - long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance   from tbl_events   having  distance <= 10  order by distance`

**Unable to find where it is**

Answer (score 5):

Here's the SQL statement that finds the closest locations within a radius of 10 miles to the given coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than and equals to 10, orders the whole query by distance. **To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371**.

```
SELECT
  id, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians($lat) )
      * cos( radians( tableLatColName ) )
      * cos( radians( tableLogColName ) - radians($long) )
      + sin ( radians($lat) )
      * sin( radians( tableLatColName ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM table_name
HAVING distance <= 10
ORDER BY distance;
```

This is using the Google Maps API v3 with a MySQL backend-

https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#findnearsql

I was working on same and found this question so Just wanted to share it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
SELECT restoran.id,restoran.restoran , (6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( -6.9831375276568055 - restoran.lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( -6.9831375276568055 * pi()/180) * COS(restoran.lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( 110.40925562381744 - restoran.lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance  from restoran having  distance <= 10 order by distance
```

`6371` numbers is for convert to km

Comment: Update proper description.