# MySQL 5.7 find rows that are close to each other by distance

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have a table of cities, example:

```
+----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+
| city_name                  | latitude          | longitude    |
+----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+
| Barrow                     |          71.29058 |   -156.78872 |
| Wainwright                 |            70.638 |    -159.9713 |
| Atqasuk                    |            70.481 |    -157.3835 |
| Clyde River                |          70.46916 |    -68.59143 |
| Prudhoe Bay                |          70.25528 |   -148.33722 |
| Nuiqsut                    |           70.2175 |   -150.97639 |
```

How can find all rows that are within a mile of another row?

Comment: You could use a distance formula

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? What are the results that you expect for this sample data?

Comment: I have drawn a blank to be honest.  I tried this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667187/mysql-select-records-with-near-distance-from-each-other but it didn't work out as I hoped.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be a very simple query, so that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

You could self join the table, use [spatial function `st_distance()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) to compute the distance between the two houses, and filter:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2
    on st_distance(
        point(t1.latitude, t1.longitude), 
        point(t2.latitude, t2.longitude)
    ) < 1609.34
```

`1609.34` is a rough estimation of how many meters a mile contains.

Comment: Nobody expecting it will be fast with many records in the table =)

Comment: I should mention that I am using MySQL 5.7.  This doesn't appear to work for that version. (edited title of question)

Comment: @Jafo: `st-distance()` was added in MySQL 5.6 (so your version has it). What do you mean by * doesn't appear to work*?

Comment: @Jafo: can you please provide a [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) where the problem can be seen?

Comment: Sure, here you go:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=05ec782b839be0f016b9eef09b61a7ec

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a POINT using `POINT(x, y)` - you get cartesian point without SRS, meaning the MySQL computes everything on a plane, using whatever units you passed as `x` and `y`.

So for example

```
select st_distance(
        point(-90, 33),
        point(-85, 33));
```

returns exactly 5. You can think of it as distance in degrees (which is useless - because 5 degrees along meridian is different from 5 degrees along parallel). Or you can think of it as the input was in meters on some plane, and the output is also in meters.

What you need (in MySQL 5.7 - in 8.0 you can use real SRS) is `st_distance_sphere` function, e.g. for the example above this returns 466234 meters.

```
select st_distance_sphere(
        point(-90, 33),
        point(-85, 33));
```