# Finding the closest location in Table2 for each location in Table1

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

The mySQL database I use currently has two tables: One called `source` and the other called `siteinfo`.

The siteinfo table is as shown:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| longitude | latitude | sitecode |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|    1.3009 | 1.900989 |        2 |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|    1.7034 | 1.20034  |        3 |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

likewise, the source table is as shown:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| longitude | latitude | sitecode |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|    1.3009 | 1.900989 |   NULL   |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

What I basically aim to do is:

For each row in the `source` table, I want to take the columns called Longitude and Latitude and compare these to the corresponding Longitude and Latitude columns in the `siteinfo` table.

Those rows in the Source table where the Long and Lat rows are most similar to those in the `siteinfo` table then have the `sitecode` column updated with the corresponding `sitecode` of the `sitecode` column in the `siteinfo` table.

For example, the long and lat values in the source table are closest in value to those in the first row of the `siteinfo` table and the `sitecode` is thus updated to 2.

To tackle this, I know I have to create two ResultSets and use while(next()) to iterate through each row of each resultset. Question is, how do I compare to find the most similar entries?

I thought of doing it brute force, using a For loop to compare say, the first row entries of the Source Resultset with every single row of the Siteinfo Resultset then increment to the second row.

However, I understand resultset work by next() function to iterate each row, which isn't the same as a for loop since I want to compare the FIRST row of one resultset against every row of another.

Second, how do I find the difference of a column entry of two result tables?

Comment: You should probably look if MySQL has support for spatial data types and queries. Then you could just do it with a single query to the server, instead of combining clumsy Java code to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to create two ResultSets. You can just create a MySQL function to calculate the [Great Circle Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/2144390) between two points ...

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION great_circle_km (lon1 DOUBLE, lat1 DOUBLE, lon2 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE)
RETURNS DOUBLE
RETURN 6371 * acos(cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lon2) - radians(lon1)) + sin(radians(lat1)) * sin(radians(lat2)))
```

... and then use an UPDATE query like so

```sql
UPDATE `source` SET `source`.`sitecode` = (
    SELECT `sitecode` FROM `siteinfo`
    ORDER BY great_circle_km(`source`.`longitude`, `source`.`latitude`, `siteinfo`.`longitude`, `siteinfo`.`latitude`)
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

Note that the above query will perform the equivalent of a CROSS JOIN (cartesian product) so the number of effective rows processed will increase dramatically for larger source tables. For example, using two 500-row tables will effectively process 250,000 rows, and using two 5,000-row tables will effectively process 25,000,000 rows.

If there could be a significant number of exact matches between the tables then it would probably be faster to update them first ...

```sql
UPDATE 
    `source` 
    INNER JOIN 
    `siteinfo` 
        ON `source`.`longitude` = `siteinfo`.`longitude` 
            AND `source`.`latitude` = `siteinfo`.`latitude`
SET `source`.`sitecode` = `siteinfo`.`sitecode`
```

... and then update the remaining rows

```sql
UPDATE `source` SET `source`.`sitecode` = (
    SELECT `sitecode` FROM `siteinfo`
    ORDER BY great_circle_km(`source`.`longitude`, `source`.`latitude`, `siteinfo`.`longitude`, `siteinfo`.`latitude`)
    LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE `source`.`sitecode` IS NULL
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and so much more efficient!

Comment: By the way, i found that analysis of larger tables(5000 rows) took quite a long time(about 2 minutes), any suggestions on improving the time efficiency?