# Contentful : Am I able to order content by using the location [within] query parameter?

Tags: php, contentful

So I'm trying to retrieve entries based on their location/coordinates, within a given radius. And have been successful using this :

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
    $query->setContentType('store')
    ->where('fields.location[within]', '-37, 144, 50');
```

However, the order in which they are returned aren't ordered by their distance to the given centre of the radius. Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `within` operator doesn't do any sorting, unlike the `near` operator. If you're trying to use `within` in the context of a circular area, which seems to be what you're doing, you can replace it with `near` and it should work the way you want it:

`fields.foo[near]=x,y,radius`

The `radius` parameter can be used to limit the search area. Give it a try, let me know if this helps!

Davide