# MySQL query mixing HAVING and ORDER BY: failing in sorting objects with a location, objects being got by distance with another location

Tags: sql, geolocation, pythagorean

I must query some objects that are close to a city. They must be sorted according to the user's location.

So I decided to write a SQL query which uses two times the Pythagoras formula.

It seems to get the good objects (close to the city), but it fails in sorting them correctly according to the user's location.

**Do you know if I correctly use SQL or if it's the formula which goes wrong?**

## Data

In the following query...

- `distance` stores the distance between the objects and the city.
- `distance_2` stores the distance between the objects and the user's location.
- `lat` and `lon` are the coordinates of the objects. The query is indeed executed in the table of the objects.

### User's location

- 47.643310
- -2.805655

### City's location

- 48.51666700
- -2.78333300

### Found objects' location

#### Closest-to-the-user object

- 47,6593484
- -2,7546085

#### Farest-to-the-user object

- 48,4962385
- -2,7642788

### Query

```
SELECT *, 

SQRT((48.51666700 - lat) * (48.51666700 - lat) + ((-2.78333300 - lon) * COS(RADIANS(lat))) * ((-2.78333300 - lon) * COS(RADIANS(lat)))) * 111.325 AS distance,

SQRT((47.64331000 - lat) * (47.64331000 - lat) + ((-2.80565500 - lon) * COS(RADIANS(lat))) * ((-2.80565500 - lon) * COS(RADIANS(lat)))) * 111.325 AS distance_2

FROM restaurants WHERE 1=1 AND visible = 1 HAVING distance < 200 ORDER BY distance_2 ASC
```

### Order of showing

The farest object is displayed before the closest, which isn't normal (see next part).

Comment: I'm expecting the Pythagorean formula to have squares in it.

Comment: Shouldn't the distance formula be like `sqrt((48.51666700 - lat) * (48.51666700 - lat) + (-2.78333300 - lon) * (-2.78333300 - lon)) as distance` ? Cosinus has nothing to do with it, unless you were using polar coordinates or something like that.

Comment: Isn't it the Harversine formula?

Comment: Plus: normally you should have the same problem than me if you execute my query with the data I provided

Comment: The distance west-east depends on the latitude (bigger distance at the equator, approaches 0 to the poles) so this part is fine at least. What I don't get is that distances for your closest object are bigger and I don't see why you still call that closest. At the very least, I would say the sorting is fine in the db

Comment: So based on the distances you had given, this is not an SQL sorting issue. The calculations are wrong and I cannot find out where it is coming from. You need to check each part of your formulae separately to see if they return what you expect. Editing your question to hide details from the people willing to help you will lead you nowhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For greater accuracy (distances 20 miles/32 kilometers), I'd suggest looking at using a Great Circle distance calculation.  We live on a globe!  There's a nice example at the link below from Stack Overflow.  This is the Haversine formula JarsofJam alluded to. 
 The author started with PHP but asked how to convert it to pure MySQL.  I believe you could, with little trouble, adapt the accepted answer to your needs.

[MySql Great Circle distance calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Do take note the proper conversion to use for the Earth's radius depending on whether you're working in kilometers or miles.