# How to use indexing for multiple table join in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

Query with multiple table joins is taking too much time. How to do the indexing for the query below:

QUERY:

```
select  ri.id, LOWER(REPLACE(ri.name,' ','-')) as urlName,ri.name,
ri.logo,
group_concat(distinct rc.cuisine order by  rc.cuisine asc SEPARATOR ',
        '
            ) as 'cuisine_string', rc.cuisine, rai.rating, rai.min_order_amount,
        rai.latitude, rai.longitude, rai.delivery_time, rdf.start_dist,
rdf.end_dist, rdf.fee, ri.address_search, rai.delivery_facility,
ri.status as 'restaurant_status', rt.day, rt.status 'opening_status',
rt.opening_time, rt.closing_time,
' - ',rdf.end_dist,
' km',' : ','₹',fee) SEPARATOR '~') as 'delivery_fee_string',
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct CONCAT(rdf.start_dist, ( SELECT  MATCH (ri.address_search) AGAINST ('Kahilipara,
                Guwahati, Assam, India') as relevance
            from  restaurant_info ri
            where  ri.id = rai.restaurant_id
              and  ri.id = rt.restaurant_id
              and  ri.id = rdf.restaurant_id
              and  ri.id = rc.restaurant_id) as ord , ( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(26.1428694) ) * cos( radians( rai.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( rai.longitude ) - radians(91.768487) ) + sin ( radians(26.1428694) ) * sin( radians( rai.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    from  restaurant_info ri
    inner join  restaurant_additional_info rai  ON ri.id = rai.restaurant_id
    inner join  restaurant_timing rt  ON ri.id = rt.restaurant_id
    inner join  restaurant_delivery_fee rdf  ON ri.id = rdf.restaurant_id
    inner join  restaurant_cuisine rc  ON ri.id = rc.restaurant_id
    where  ri.status = 1
      and  rt.status = 1
      and  rt.day = lower(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a'))
      and  rai.delivery_facility != 1
      and  rai.min_order_amount <= 100
      and  rai.rating <= ''
      and  MATCH (ri.address_search) AGAINST ('Kahilipara, Guwahati,
                Assam, India'
                 )
      and  rt.opening_time < '12:40:21'
      and  rt.closing_time > '12:40:21'
    group by  ri.id
    having  rdf.start_dist = 0
      and  distance < 3.10686
    order by  distance asc
    LIMIT  100 OFFSET 0
```

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM- This Query is taking 8.5 seconds to run. My application contains 1-2 such queries.Therefore loading time approaches 1 min on server.

Can anyone help me to apply indexing on this query?

Comment: Look into MySQL's geospatial support if you really need performance here.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN on the query... but I guess it's the calculation that consumes the time. How many reocrds are there?

Comment: 2000 plus records are there and I am using join for 3 tables @LarsStegelitz

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This question is not a duplicate of anyone. I am fetching based on address inputted on form then matching it with my tables against a distance.

Comment: Please try one or more of the indexing techniques in the duplicate link.

Comment: The duplicate link only on the getting data according to the distance and not indexes which I don't need. My query is already giving me the desired result but I need to look into the performance of the query so I am asking your help on implementing indexes in this particular query. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I reopened because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula did not cover all the issues being raised.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the various tables.  Also, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

```
where  ri.status = 1
  and  rt.status = 1
  and  rt.day = lower(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a'))
  and  rai.delivery_facility != 1
  and  rai.min_order_amount <= 100
  and  rai.rating <= ''
  and  MATCH (ri.address_search) AGAINST ('Kahilipara, Guwahati, Assam, India')
  and  rt.opening_time < '12:40:21'
  and  rt.closing_time > '12:40:21'
group by  ri.id
having  rdf.start_dist = 0
  and  distance < 3.10686
order by  distance asc
LIMIT  100 OFFSET 0
```

Since there is a `FULLTEXT` condition in the `WHERE` clause, it will probably do that first.  However, if there are thousands of rows in those areas, we need to dig further.

`rai.rating <= ''` seems very strange; what are you expect from "<=''"?

`having  rdf.start_dist = 0` -- it seems like this belongs in the `WHERE` clause, not `HAVING`.

One big problem is you have range tests scattered across multiple tables:

```
rt -- just a certain day of the week
rai -- limited amount, etc
ri -- certain regions
rt -- time range, complicated by using 2 columns
```

Even if these fields were in the same table, it would still be costly to compute.

`distance < ...` -- This could be optimized with a "bounding box", as discussed in the link, but it won't help much because of the other issues.

`JOIN ... GROUP BY id` -- This is probably an "explode-implode" scenario.  What happens is the `JOINs` expand the number of 'rows' being looked at by joining 1:many, etc.  Then the `GROUP BY` is trying to get back to just one row per id.  If it weren't for all the filtering, there are workarounds.

Meanwhile, the `GROUP BY` may be improperly used.  See `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

`order by distance LIMIT ..` -- The query is forced to gather all the rows (thousands?) before sorting and delivering up to 100.

`rt.day = lower(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a'))` - with a suitable collation, you don't need `LOWER()`.

`MATCH (ri.address_search) ..` and `distance < ..` seem redundant.

Why are there 5 tables, each keyed by "restaurant id"?  (There could be valid reasons, but it looks fishy.)  Are they 1:1 or 1:many?

Comment: They are 1:1 relationship. That is why we have restaurant id keyed in each of the tables. @Rick James