# Laravel use append attirbute inside a query in controller or scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have done the following: I have a table called group that has longitude and latitude which is essentially a location of the group. Then I have an `append` which calculates the distance from the user.

**Group Model:**

```
class Group extends Authenticatable
{

  protected $fillable = [
     'lng',
     'lat'
  ];

  protected $appends = [
     'distance_from_user'
  ];

  public function getDistanceFromUserAttribute(query) {
     
        $ip = Request::ip();
        $coordinates = \Location::get($ip);
        $radius = 4000;

        $latFrom = deg2rad($coordinates->latitude); // current user's lat
        $lonFrom = deg2rad($coordinates->longitude); // current user's long
        $latTo = deg2rad($this->lat); // this is coming from the database
        $lonTo = deg2rad($this->lng); // this is coming from the database
      
        $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
        $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
      
        $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));

        return $angle * 6371;
  }
}
```

What I want to do now is USE that `distance from user` in a where clause like below in a scope, which sits in the same model as above.

**Scope Inside Group Model:**

```
public function scopeGetAllGroups($query)
{
    return Groups::get()->where('distance_from_user', '<', 25);
}
```

But the `distance_from_user` is not available at this point when I use the scope.  How can i manage this so that I can use the calculated distance in a query.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use a model accessor in a query, but you can use to filter the resulting collection.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter But what if the resulting collection is 1000 records?  The distance is one of the main ways I filter.

Comment: You'll have to translate the calculation being done in the accessor method into the query language. For example, [MySQL + Haversine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/9556193).

Comment: @DigitalDrifter So do the whole querying in a scope or the controller straight.

Comment: add your ```//some calculation that returns the distance from the user's long and late``` to question to help you

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh I added my calculation there

Comment: do you have any problem in storing distance_from_user in your database like calculating it at the time of storing in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments stated, you cannot use the Query Builder to filter by an accessor. You *can* however, use the `filter()` method on a Collection.

```php
// This won't work
Group::where('distance_from_user', '<', 25)->get();
```

```php
// This should work
$groups = Group::get()->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->distance_from_user < 25;
});
// Or using PHP 7.4's shorthand Closure
$groups = Group::get()->filter(fn ($item) => $item->distance_from_user < 25);
```

The problem is the fact you are querying all the records from the database and building a huge Collection of Models. That can really slow down your application. There is a solution for this problem: LazyCollections. Instead of using `->get()`, use `->cursor()` to return a LazyCollection instance.

```php
$groups = Group::cursor()->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->distance_from_user < 25;
});
// Or using PHP 7.4's shorthand Closure
$groups = Group::cursor()->filter(fn ($item) => $item->distance_from_user < 25);
```

This might feel wrong but it uses little to no memory. A cave-at: It doesn't work well with eager loading relationships. Normal joins are fine though.

At this point, `$groups` can be iterated over but it's not a Collection. If you want to turn it into a "normal" collection, just append [`->collect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-collect) at the end. You can also do some database filtering before using `->cursor()`

```php
$example = Group::where(...)->select(...)->join(...)->cursor()->filter(....)->collect();
```

More on the subject:

https://josephsilber.com/posts/2020/07/29/lazy-collections-in-laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#using-cursors

Comment: I apologize for my delay (3 years almost) in responding to your response.  I am truly grateful for it.